# How do I replace values along z-axis in Numpy 3D array based on 2D index and 1D value vector

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm struggling to understand array indexing it seems.

What is given:

I do have a 3d array like so:

```
a_3d = np.zeros((3,3,3))
```

An 2d index array:

```
a_2d_index = np.array([[0,0,1], [0,0,0], [0,1,1]]).astype('bool')
```

And values to place into 3d array at x,y location:

```
a_1d_fill = np.array([10,20,30])
```

Now, I do want to use a_2d_index to find the locations in a_3d and vertically place the a_1d_fill at this x,y position...

The final outcome should look like this:

```
a_3d := [[[0,0, 10],
          [0,0,  0],
          [0,10,10]],
         [[0,0, 20],
          [0,0,  0],
          [0,20,20]],
         [[0,0, 30],
          [0,0,  0],
          [0,30,30]]]
```

This will be used on very large array so memory efficiency and speed are crucial... (little copying, preferably in-place modification)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [26]: a_3d = np.zeros((3,3,3), dtype=int)

In [27]: a_2d_index = np.array([[0,0,1], [0,0,0], [0,1,1]]).astype('bool')

In [28]: a_1d_fill = np.array([10,20,30])

In [29]: a_3d[:,a_2d_index] = a_1d_fill[:,np.newaxis]

In [30]: a_3d
Out[30]:
array([[[ 0,  0, 10],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 10, 10]],

       [[ 0,  0, 20],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 20, 20]],

       [[ 0,  0, 30],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 30, 30]]])
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks clean!

One question so. This does not work if I have a 4d array and I want to apply  to a slice of the 4D array (with shape (10,3,3,3).

Say I want to do this on the slice with index 2:

    a_4d_array[2, :, a_2d_index] = a_1d_fill[:, np.newaxis]

fails in my script with a shape mismatch

Comment: I admit that I'm also confused about why those two lines are not equivalent.  I expected them to do the same thing, but found that they do not.

Comment: `a_4d_array[2, :, idx]` is a case of (tricky) mixed basic and advanced indexing, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing.  Its shape is the transpose of what you might expect, with the `idx` shape first, and the slice shape last.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a little bit of explanation and intuition might help future readers to better understand slicing.
I'm (shamelessly) using [Stuart Berg's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42876319/2956066) to explain the users to get an intuitive feel for slicing.

Array & mask definition:

```
In [57]: a_3d        # array with unique numbers for better understanding.
Out[57]: 
array([[[13, 14, 15],
        [23, 24, 25],
        [33, 34, 35]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2],
        [30, 31, 32],
        [40, 41, 42]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Understand the above 3D array as three slices of `3x3` array, with the top most array having index `0` and center one having index `1` and the bottom one having index `2`.

Boolean Mask:

```
In [58]: a_2d_index
Out[58]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Now, let's slice the array `a_3d` using the boolean mask `a_2d_index`

```
In [68]: a_3d[:, a_2d_index]   # : means apply the mask to all the slices(here 3)
Out[68]: 
array([[15, 34, 35],
       [ 5, 10, 11],
       [ 2, 41, 42]], dtype=uint8)
```

Okay, now we get the above result. Why and how? So, imagine like this: we take the boolean-mask array and just superimpose on the array `a_3d` over each of its slices.

Now, wherever we have boolean value `True` in the mask, that corresponding element in array `a_3d` will (glow?) and contribute to the result array. This happens with each slice as we place the mask over each slice (since we've used `:`, we do this for all the slices in array `a_3d`).

So Yay, slicing is done! Now, we want to assign new values (where the mask has boolean value `True`).

Assigning new values:

```
In [69]: a_1d_fill
Out[69]: array([10, 20, 30])
```

This is the 1D array that we have. But, the mask is 2D array. So, we change this to 2D using `np.newaxis`

```
In [70]: a_2d_fill = a_1d_fill[:, np.newaxis]

In [71]: a_2d_fill
Out[71]: 
array([[10],
       [20],
       [30]])


In [73]: a_3d[:, a_2d_index] = a_2d_fill
```

Now, this assignment will copy the value `10` to indices in the first slice where the boolean mask has `True` value, then copy value `20` to indices in second slice where the boolean mask has value `True` and finally copy value `30` to indices in third slice where the boolean mask has value `True`.

And the final result looks like:

```
In [74]: a_3d
Out[74]: 
array([[[13, 14, 10],
        [23, 24, 25],
        [33, 10, 10]],

       [[ 3,  4, 20],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 20, 20]],

       [[ 0,  1, 30],
        [30, 31, 32],
        [40, 30, 30]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Phew! That was really long. So, in short, the result array should have values `10`, `20`, & `30` in first, second, and third slices (where boolean mask has value `True`) respectively.

---

P.S.: Slicing provides *views* or *references* of the original array. So, when we *change* values using slicing, this will affect the original array. Thus, this is an in-place modification.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that helped!