# Replace elements in an Nx3x2 numpy array with elements located in an Mx2 numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have the following `xy` numpy array which represents the locations of the vertices of some triangles:

```
array([[[ 0.30539728, 49.82845203],
        [ 0.67235022, 49.95042185],
        [ 0.268982  , 49.95195348]],
       [[ 0.268982  , 49.95195348],
        [ 0.67235022, 49.95042185],
        [ 0.27000135, 50.16334035]],
       ...
       [[ 1.00647459, 50.25958169],
        [ 0.79479121, 50.3010079 ],
        [ 0.67235022, 49.95042185]],
       [[ 0.79479121, 50.3010079 ],
        [ 0.6886783 , 50.25867683],
        [ 0.67235022, 49.95042185]]])
```

Here, it's an array of shape `(10, 3, 2)` but it could as well be `(5, 3, 2)` or `(18, 3, 2)`, you name it. In any case it's of shape `(N, 3, 2)`.
I have another numpy array `to_replace` of shape `(4, 2)` but it could as well be `(6, 2)` or `(7, 2)`, but always of shape `(M, 2)`:

```
array([[ 1.08267406, 49.88690993],
       [ 1.1028248 , 50.01440407],
       [ 0.74114309, 49.73183549],
       [ 1.08267406, 49.88690993]])
```

It represents the locations of pairs of coordinates that can be found in my first array. Note that each of these pairs is present at least once in `xy` but could be present more than once.
Finally, I have a third array `replace_by` of which shape `(8,)` (or of shape `(M*2)` based on the indication above) and which values are meant to replace exactly those contained in `to_replace` in my first `xy` array. It looks like this:

```
array([ 0.87751214, 49.91866589,  0.88758751, 49.98241296,  0.70674665, 49.84112867,  0.87751214, 49.91866589])
```

So basically all pairs `[1.08267406, 49.88690993]` in `xy` should be replaced by `[0.87751214, 49.91866589]` for example.

My current code looks like this but it works only if `to_replace` and `replace_by` are strictly of shape `(2, 2)`.

```
indices = (xy == to_replace[:, None][:, None])[0]
xy[indices] = replace_by
```

I [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752314/how-to-correctly-mask-3d-array-with-numpy) [looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876202/how-do-i-replace-values-along-z-axis-in-numpy-3d-array-based-on-2d-index-and-1d) at a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696158/how-to-mask-with-3d-array-and-2d-array-numpy) of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781282/vectorization-too-many-indices-for-array) and actually got inspired by some of them but I still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.isclose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to compare rows and then use `.all(axis=2)` to find where all last rows are the same. Numpy will broadcast each row to fit `xy` shape.

```
import numpy as np
xy = np.array([[[ 0.30539728, 49.82845203],
        [ 0.67235022, 49.95042185],
        [ 0.268982  , 49.95195348]],
       [[ 0.268982  , 49.95195348],
        [ 0.67235022, 49.95042185],
        [ 0.27000135, 50.16334035]],
       [[ 1.00647459, 50.25958169],
        [ 0.79479121, 50.3010079 ],
        [ 0.67235022, 49.95042185]],
       [[ 0.79479121, 50.3010079 ],
        [ 0.6886783 , 50.25867683],
        [ 0.67235022, 49.95042185]]])
xy_start = xy.copy()


to_replace = np.array([[ 1.08267406, 49.88690993],
       [ 1.1028248 , 50.01440407],
       # [ 0.74114309, 49.73183549],
       [ 0.6886783 , 50.25867683],
       [ 1.08267406, 49.88690993]])

replace_by = np.array([ 0.87751214, 49.91866589,  0.88758751, 49.98241296,  0.70674665, 49.84112867,  0.87751214, 49.91866589])
replace_by_reshaped = replace_by.reshape(-1, 2)

for i, row in enumerate(to_replace):
    xy[np.isclose(xy, row).all(axis=2)] = replace_by_reshaped[i]
print(xy_start)
# [[[ 0.30539728 49.82845203]
#   [ 0.67235022 49.95042185]
#   [ 0.268982   49.95195348]]

#  [[ 0.268982   49.95195348]
#   [ 0.67235022 49.95042185]
#   [ 0.27000135 50.16334035]]

#  [[ 1.00647459 50.25958169]
#   [ 0.79479121 50.3010079 ]
#   [ 0.67235022 49.95042185]]

#  [[ 0.79479121 50.3010079 ]
#   [ 0.6886783  50.25867683]
#   [ 0.67235022 49.95042185]]]
print(xy)
# [[[ 0.30539728 49.82845203]
#   [ 0.67235022 49.95042185]
#   [ 0.268982   49.95195348]]

#  [[ 0.268982   49.95195348]
#   [ 0.67235022 49.95042185]
#   [ 0.27000135 50.16334035]]

#  [[ 1.00647459 50.25958169]
#   [ 0.79479121 50.3010079 ]
#   [ 0.67235022 49.95042185]]

#  [[ 0.79479121 50.3010079 ]
#   [ 0.70674665 49.84112867]
#   [ 0.67235022 49.95042185]]]
```

**EDIT**

`.all(axis=2)` shrink axis=2 to `True` if all values along axis=2 are `True` and `False` else. I think little 2d example made it clear what is happening here.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> np.isclose(a, [0, 1])
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False]])
>>> np.isclose(a, [0, 1]).all(axis=1)
array([ True, False, False])
>>> a[np.isclose(a, [0, 1]).all(axis=1)]
array([[0, 1]])
>>> a[np.isclose(a, [0, 1]).all(axis=1)] = [12, 14]
>>> a
array([[12, 14],
       [ 0,  2],
       [ 3,  4]])
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Could you please provide more information on what's the purpose of this `.all(axis=2)` and what it's doing please? I'm not sure to get how the magic is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy-indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains functionality to solve this problem in a vectorized and elegant manner.

Given the arrays as you have defined them, this one-liner should do the trick:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi    
npi.remap(xy.reshape(-1, 2), to_replace, replace_by.reshape(-1, 2)).reshape(-1, 3, 2)
```